# Move items in list from front to the back

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm new to python and programming in general, so I feel like I'm trying to wrap my head around the simplest of things...

Let's say I have a list of 12 items:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

and a variable that matches one of the items in the list:

```
b = 7
```

Now I want to find that match in the list and move every item **before** the match to the end of the list in the same order like so:

```
a = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How would I go about doing this in python 3.4.2?

The match could be for any item at any index, but the number of items will always be the same (12).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use slicing of list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> idx = a.index(7)
>>> a = a[idx:] + a[:idx]
>>> a
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that this will throw a `ValueError` if the value being searched is not found in the array, in which case you will need to capture it using `try`-`except` block

Comment: Thank-you. I haven't really learned about .index() yet. I guess that's why I couldn't find a solution to my problem.
3 hours later and I've finished creating a small program that creates different musical chords depending on the key the music is in (defined by the user). :P 

Just for practice.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to simultaneously use `append` and `pop`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> idx = a.index(7)
>>> for _ in range(idx):
...     a.append(a.pop(0))
>>> a
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I do not advocate using this over the slicing method because this will be very slow (`list`s are not optimized for `pop`ing from the front).  I just mention it here to show another method that I believe is a little bit easier to understand at first glance.